# nginx + php fpm security issue?

Tags: php, nginx

I am new user of nginx + php-pfm, but I am a little bit confused about security.

For example I am running a few pools with different uid/gid as TCP sockets. So theoritically it is 
possible that any local shell user can connect to 127.0.0.1 9000 OR 9001 or any other FPM port and
send php code to execute with different uids? How to avoid that? (file sockets is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

You can't send code to be executed, only path to file to execute. And it has to be readable by the user your FPM pool runs as. So this bad user would have to be able to create a file with permissions to be read by FPM.